# Compiler error: 1 unresolved external

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some C++ code of a program that will compute the average of 10 integers using functions.

I've got everything right except for one error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl sumFunc(int)" (?sumFunc@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main

Can anyone point me in the right direction of fixing this code so I can compile this? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int sumFunc (int);
double averageFunc (double&);

int const size = 10;

int main()  
{ 
int integer = 0;
double average;


cout << "Enter ten numbers: ";
sumFunc(integer);
averageFunc(average);
cout << "The average is " << average << endl;

getch();

return 0;
}  

int sumFunc(int integer[])
{
int sum = 0;

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cin >> integer[index];
        sum = sum + integer[index];
    }

return sum;
}


double averageFunc(double& average)
{
int sum = 0;

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        average = sum / 10.0;
    }

return average;
}
```

Comment: You've declared `sumFunc` as `int sumFunc (int);` but defined it as `int sumFunc(int integer[])`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function prototype

`int sumFunc (int);`

Doesn't match the function declaration

`int sumFunc(int integer[])`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but do you know how I would fix that to match up with each other?

Comment: Change the prototype to match the declaration exactly. They should both read `int sumFunc(int integer[])`